# Countdown to tomorrow date in javascript?

Tags: javascript, countdown

I have this code:
And its not working. It's always showing -7 hours, it should count to next 7:00.
How to do this?

```
 function ShowTime() {

var now = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
var hrs = 7-now.getHours();
var mins = 60-now.getMinutes();
var secs = 60-now.getSeconds();
timeLeft = "" +hrs+' hours '+mins+' minutes '+secs+' seconds';
    $("#countdown").html(timeLeft);
}
    var countdown;
    function StopTime() {
        clearInterval(countdown);                           
    }

setInterval(ShowTime ,1000);
```

Comment: I suggest to do all time manipulations in JavaScript using Moment.js library

Answer (score 1):

`getHours();` The getHours() method returns the hour (from 0 to 23) of the specified date and time.
So change your code `7-now.getHours();` returns negative when the time is past 7